# Can I use an ArcGIS Enterprise developer subscription license with AWS's BYOL solution for ArcGIS Enterprise?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

AWS provides an image for ArcGIS enterprise 10.9.1 that you can buy and use by bringing your own license. ESRI provides a way to buy a license for a developer subscription of ArcGIS Enterprise. Can that license be used with AWS's image?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service related question, not a programming question. Contact the vendor directly for questions related to the allowable uses of your license. We do not offer support for licensing related questions here, as indicated in the [help/on-topic] guidelines.